# Factorial-design diagrams in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd highly appreciate if someone could give me hand to draw this diagram in `TikZ`.

[image]

Comment: Generally, questions of the type "Can someone do this for me?" are strongly discouraged. You should make an effort to show what you've done so far to solve the problem, show the code you have so far, and specify where exactly you're stuck.
As a pointer to where to start, you could take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28363/how-to-pick-a-plane-inside-a-cube-in-pst-3dplot/28486#28486

Comment: AB and BC seem odd since we cannot really distinguish where the blue and red surfaces cross.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Sketch](http://www.frontiernet.net/~eugene.ressler/) - a program to generate 3D drawings using `PSTricks` or `TPGF/TikZ`.

Comment: Perhaps [how to draw a cube with tikz where all faces have a distinct color](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28284/how-to-draw-a-cube-with-tikz-where-all-faces-have-a-distinct-color/28286#28286) can help you get started.

Comment: From the link I mentioned, you should easily be able to to A, B, and C just by choosing the colors and opacity of each plane.  Enable the debug options to see where each point is and then you can produce the last three by connecting the appropriate points.  To finish it off, add a line where the planes intersect as mentioned by pluton.  If you make an attempt and get stuck please edit your question and we can help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making overlay figures in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45239/making-overlay-figures-in-tikz)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm conscious this question is two years old, but I'm bored. Here is my take on this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}

\newcommand\drawplane[2]
{%
    \draw
    [
        thick,
        opacity=.6,
        draw=#2,
        fill=#2!60,
    ] #1 -- cycle;%
}

\newcommand\drawonecase[4]
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

        \tikzset
        {
            edgevis/.style={black},
            edgehid/.style={dashed,black},
        }

        \def\vertexradius{.7pt}

        \coordinate (OOO) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (OOI) at (xyz cs:z=1);
        \coordinate (OIO) at (xyz cs:y=1);
        \coordinate (OII) at (xyz cs:y=1,z=1);
        \coordinate (IOO) at (xyz cs:x=1);
        \coordinate (IOI) at (xyz cs:x=1,z=1);
        \coordinate (IIO) at (xyz cs:x=1,y=1);
        \coordinate (III) at (xyz cs:x=1,y=1,z=1);

        \drawplane{#1}{#2}
        \drawplane{#3}{#4}

        \draw[edgevis] (OOI) -- (OII) -- (OIO) -- (IIO) -- (IOO) -- (IOI) -- cycle;
        \draw[edgevis] (III) -- (IIO);
        \draw[edgevis] (III) -- (IOI);
        \draw[edgevis] (III) -- (OII);
        \draw[edgehid] (OOO) -- (OOI);
        \draw[edgehid] (OOO) -- (OIO);
        \draw[edgehid] (OOO) -- (IOO);

        \draw (OOO) circle (\vertexradius);
        \draw (OOI) circle (\vertexradius);
        \draw (OIO) circle (\vertexradius);
        \draw (OII) circle (\vertexradius);
        \draw (IOO) circle (\vertexradius);
        \draw (IOI) circle (\vertexradius);
        \draw (IIO) circle (\vertexradius);
        \draw (III) circle (\vertexradius);

    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \drawonecase
                {(OOO) -- (OOI) -- (OII) -- (OIO)}{red}
                {(IOO) -- (IOI) -- (III) -- (IIO)}{blue}
            &
            \drawonecase
                {(OOO) -- (IOO) -- (IIO) -- (OIO)}{blue}
                {(OOI) -- (IOI) -- (III) -- (OII)}{red}
            &
            \drawonecase
                {(OOO) -- (IOO) -- (IOI) -- (OOI)}{red}
                {(OIO) -- (IIO) -- (III) -- (OII)}{blue}
            \\
            $A$ & $B$ & $C$
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Main effects}
    \end{subfigure}
    \par
    \vspace{1em}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \drawonecase
                {(OOI) -- (OII) -- (IIO) -- (IOO)}{blue}
                {(OOO) -- (OIO) -- (III) -- (IOI)}{red}
            &
            \drawonecase
                {(OII) -- (OIO) -- (IOO) -- (IOI)}{red}
                {(OOI) -- (OOO) -- (IIO) -- (III)}{blue}
            &
            \drawonecase
                {(OOI) -- (IOI) -- (IIO) -- (OIO)}{blue}
                {(OII) -- (III) -- (IOO) -- (OOO)}{red}
            \\
            $AB$ & $AC$ & $BC$
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Two-factor interactions}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{%
        Geometric presentation of contrast.
        In each case, high levels are highlighted in blue, low levels in red.%
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jubobs for your nice answer. I solved this problem lot time  ago ([See here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45239/4821), and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85799/4821) but forgot to mention here. Anyway thanks for your effort and for nice answer.

Answer (score 7):

A few pointers:

- You can use XYZ coordinates (origin would be the lower left of the back face), see [PGF manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), page 124
- Use the `dashed` option for dashed lines, see page 158
- to see lines and surfaces behind the colored surfaces, use the `draw opacity` option, see page 234
- for the small circles at the corners, use circular arrow tips, see page 257

If special problems arise, please update your answer, and please then include what you've done so far.