# how to use \@Alph in the name of node inside a foreach?

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming

In this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45239/making-overlay-figures-in-tikz/45245#45245) we use a lot of possibilities to define a cube. One idea is to name the vertices. I would like to find something to create these names automatically. In my last example in the question, I used nodes named 000,010,...,111. Now I would like to transform these names (or references, I don't know what is the exact term in english) in the conventional names A,B,...,H. To make this I use three loops to get 8 numbers in binary representation. 
I convert these numbers to base 10. Logically the formula  is `1+\x+2*\y+4*\z` but I wanted to 
invert two names because I would get A,B,C,D and not A,B,D,C so I use a little trick :
   `1+\x+2*\y+4*\z+\y*(\y-2*\x)`.

With a counter `cnt` and the macro `\Alph` no problem but now (**it's my quesion**) I would like to avoid the use of a counter and to replace `\Alph` by `\@Alph` but something goes wrong.

This little code works

```
\makeatletter
\def\tmp{10}
\def\macro{\@Alph{\tmp}}  
\macro 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(\macro){\macro};
  \draw (J)--++(5,1);  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My main code works also

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{tikz}         
\begin{document}    
\newcounter{cnt} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[ x={(-0.5cm,-0.5cm)}, y={(1cm,0cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)},
                     every node/.style={shape=circle,draw}]

\foreach \z in {0,1}
  \foreach \y in {0,1}
    \foreach  \x in {0,1}
        {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nb}{1+\x+2*\y+4*\z+\y*(\y-2*\x)} 
         \setcounter{cnt} {\nb} 
         \node (\Alph{cnt}) at (4*\x,4*\y,4*\z) {\Alph{cnt}};
         }%    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to write something like that

**Wrong code**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-0.5cm,-0.5cm)}, y={(1cm,0cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)},
                    every node/.style={shape=circle,draw}]
\foreach \z in {0,1}
  \foreach \y in {0,1}
    \foreach  \x in {0,1}
        {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nb}{1+\x+2*\y+4*\z+\y*(\y-2*\x)} 
         \makeatletter
         \def\name{\@Alph{\nb}} 
         \node (\name) at (4*\x,4*\y,4*\z) {\name};
         } %
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I get a lot of insults and particularly:

```
  Missing \endcsname inserted.
  <to be read again> 
  \spacefactor
```

**Where is my mistake ?**

The result is a future cube :

[image]

Comment: Your new code seems to work fine here. [File List](http://pastie.org/3429449)

Comment: How's `\nb` defined?

Comment: @AndreyVihrov I update my question and I put the complete wrong code (I work with pgf cvs 2.1)

Comment: @egreg `\nb` is first a number between 0 and 7 with `\x+2*\y+4*\z`, the normal representation base 10. I get 000, 100, 010, 110, 001, 101, 011, 111, to get 000, 100, 110, 010, 001, 101, 111, 011 I added \y*(\y-2*\x) and finally to get a number between 1 and 8 I added 1. Voilà !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The catcode of a character is fixed when it is read from input. When the `\foreach` macro reads its argument, the catcode of `@` is still "other", because `\makeatletter` is not executed at the time when the argument is being read. When TeX processes the expansion of `\foreach`, it finds `\@`, which is a macro expanding to `\spacefactor \@m`, and the characters `Alph`, which is not what was intended.

`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` normally should be used outside macros. Place `\def\name{\@Alph{\nb}}` in the preamble and the code will work (this is what I did when I commented that it works). Plus, redefinining `\name` each time is slower.

If you insist on keeping the `\def` inside, use `\csname` explicitly to call `\@Alph`:

```
\def\name{\csname @Alph\endcsname{\nb}}
```

Comment: An alternative is to set `\makeatletter\def\name{\@Alph{\nb}}\makeatother` just before the first `\foreach` so it becomes a "scratch" variable for that `tikzpicture` only.