# types of systems of linear equations and intersection of planes, with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-3dplot

Is there a simple way using tikz to graph a plane from its equation (like those of the systems on the right side, e.g. 2x +3y -z = 11), and that allows me to represent the intersection of two or three of them (even four)?
If possible, I additionally need it to allow me to have flat colors in each of the planes involved and not to be represented by pieces as suggested by some of the solutions I have seen.

I want to represent graphically to my students all the possibilities that can be presented with a system of linear equations with three unknowns, in a way similar to the one in the image I include.
I have been reading the material related to this topic for three days and I have not found a completely satisfactory solution (or maybe there is one, but I have not appreciated it properly).
I know a bit about tikz, pgfplots and tikz-3dplot (and I come from the old school of pstricks).
[image]

Comment: These posts could provide a starting point (there should be plenty more on this site): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506524/how-to-draw-planes-intersection-like-this, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604334/how-to-plot-the-3d-graph-of-the-following-three-inequalities-in-latex-e-g-tik