# tikz computer component 3d library?

Tags: tikz-pgf

has someone created a set of 3d tikz sketches for common computer hardware?

(I have been trying to design an internal 3-D CD-ROM drive, starting from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/annotated-3d-box/, but the more I tinker with it, the less it looks to me like a CD-ROM drive.  On the bright side, my doodles with ipad drawing programs don't look any better, either.)

Comment: As of now, there are two official 3d libraries: `3d` and `perspective`. I doubt that a collection of hardware pictures will become parts of an official Ti*k*Z library anytime soon. If you are interested in an automatized ordering of the faces of the shapes, you may want to look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509163/194703).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach for you, I think, is [embedding external images within a tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115087/how-can-i-embed-an-external-image-within-a-tikzpicture-environment).

But if you really want to have sketches drawn with tikz, 3d approach is less sutable than 2d. Below you can find my humble attempt to draw a CD drive. I use [TikzEdt](http://www.tikzedt.org/) to make it.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{border/.style={rounded corners=7pt,line width=5pt,draw=black!70,fill=black!20}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[border] (-5.5,2.5)--(0,0)--(4,2)--(-1.5,4.5)--cycle;
\draw[border] (-5.5,2.5)--(-5.5,1)--(0,-1.5)--(0,0)--cycle;
\draw[border] (0,-1.5)--(4,0.5)--(4,2)--(0,0)--cycle;

\draw[draw=none,top color=black!80, bottom color=black!70] (0.4,-0.95)--(3.6,0.65)--(3.6,1.4)--(0.4,-0.2)--cycle;

\begin{scope}
\clip (0.4,-0.575)--(3.6,1.025)--(5,1.025)--(5,-2)--(0.4,-2)--cycle;
\draw[line width=5pt,draw=black!50,fill=black!10] (2.2,0.1) ellipse (2 and 1);
\draw[line width=5pt,draw=none,fill=black!20] (2.2,0.1) ellipse (1.3 and 0.65);
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=black!10,top color=black!50, bottom color=black!70] (2.2,0.1) ellipse (0.5 and 0.25);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]