# How draw three intersecting golden rectangles to create the vertices of an icosahedron?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3d

[image: icosahedron from 3 golden rectangles]

How create in Tikz the three intersecting golden rectangles as in the image?

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please provide a full [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) which reproduces the issue, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ti*k*Z does not have a 3d engine, so we need to draw the elements in the right order. For the case of planes, [some tools have been developed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509163), which I am using here. You will need the [3dtools library](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools) to compile this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}
\begin{document}
% define a command for the projections (to become a part of the library)
\makeatletter
\newcommand\GetProj[2]{\begingroup
  \pgfutil@tempcnta=0%
  \edef\pgfutil@tmpa{0}%
  \pgfutil@for\my@item:={#1}\do{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\mycoord{TD("\my@item")}%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempcnta by1\relax
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpa}{\pgfutil@tmpa-screendepth(\mycoord)}%
  }%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{#2}{\pgfutil@tmpa/\pgfutil@tempcnta}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle#2\endgroup}
\makeatother  
% counter for 3d ordering  
\newcounter{tdorder}
% set a sufficient number of layers (for more complex scenarios you need more)
\foreach \X in {1,...,40}
{\pgfdeclarelayer{layer\X}
\ifnum\X=1
\xdef\LstLayers{layer\X}
\else
\xdef\LstLayers{\LstLayers,layer\X}
\fi}
\pgfsetlayers\LstLayers
\tikzset{closed polygon/.style={insert path={foreach \Coord [count=\nCoord] in {#1}
 {\ifnum\nCoord=1
  \Coord
 \else
  -- \Coord
 \fi} -- cycle}},polygon/.style={insert path={foreach \Coord [count=\nCoord] in {#1}
 {\ifnum\nCoord=1
  \Coord
 \else
  -- \Coord
 \fi}}},
 vertex poly/.style={insert path={foreach \Coord [count=\nCoord] in {#1}
 {\ifnum\nCoord=1
  \Coord node[vertex,vname=\Coord]{}
 \else
  -- \Coord node[vertex,vname=\Coord]{}
 \fi}}},vertex/.style={circle,draw,fill=white,inner sep=2pt},
 vname/.code={\def\vnameadd(##1){\edef\myvname{v-##1}}%
 \expandafter\vnameadd#1\relax
 \tikzset{alias=\myvname}%
 }}
% main code
\foreach \X in {5,15,...,355}
{\tdplotsetmaincoords{90+30*sin(\X)}{\X}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=pi,
    font=\sffamily,fill opacity=1,
    declare function={phi=(1+sqrt(5))/2;},
    line join=round,line cap=round]
  \path[tdplot_screen_coords,use as bounding box] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
  % define the vertices (there are certainly superior naming conventions)
  \path (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
     (phi/2,1/2,0)  coordinate (xypp) (phi/2,0,0)  coordinate (xyp0)
     (phi/2,-1/2,0)  coordinate (xypm) (0,1/2,0)  coordinate (xy0p)
     (-phi/2,-1/2,0)  coordinate (xymm) (-phi/2,0,0)  coordinate (xym0)
     (-phi/2,1/2,0)  coordinate (xymp) (0,-1/2,0)  coordinate (xy0m)
     (0,phi/2,1/2)  coordinate (yzpp) (0,phi/2,0) coordinate (yzp0) 
     (0,phi/2,-1/2)  coordinate (yzpm) (0,0,1/2) coordinate (yz0p) 
     (0,-phi/2,-1/2)  coordinate (yzmm) (0,-phi/2,0) coordinate (yzm0) 
     (0,-phi/2,1/2)  coordinate (yzmp) (0,0,-1/2) coordinate (yz0m) 
     (1/2,0,phi/2)  coordinate (xzpp) (0,0,phi/2)  coordinate (xzp0) 
     (-1/2,0,phi/2)  coordinate (xzpm) (1/2,0,0)  coordinate (xz0p) 
     (-1/2,0,-phi/2)  coordinate (xzmm) (0,0,-phi/2)  coordinate (xzm0) 
     (1/2,0,-phi/2)  coordinate (xzmp) (-1/2,0,0)  coordinate (xz0m) ;
  % define the plane data as a list of <drawing options>/<shape>/<vertices> 
  \def\PlaneData{%
  {draw=none,fill=red}/closed polygon/{(xypp),(xyp0),(O),(xy0p)},%
  {draw=none,fill=red}/closed polygon/{(xypm),(xyp0),(O),(xy0m)},%
  {draw=none,fill=red}/closed polygon/{(xymp),(xym0),(O),(xy0p)},%
  {draw=none,fill=red}/closed polygon/{(xymm),(xym0),(O),(xy0m)},%
  {draw=none,fill=blue}/closed polygon/{(yzpp),(yzp0),(O),(yz0p)},%
  {draw=none,fill=blue}/closed polygon/{(yzpm),(yzp0),(O),(yz0m)},%
  {draw=none,fill=blue}/closed polygon/{(yzmp),(yzm0),(O),(yz0p)},%
  {draw=none,fill=blue}/closed polygon/{(yzmm),(yzm0),(O),(yz0m)},%
  {draw=none,fill=green!70!black}/closed polygon/{(xzpp),(xzp0),(O),(xz0p)},%
  {draw=none,fill=green!70!black}/closed polygon/{(xzpm),(xzp0),(O),(xz0m)},%
  {draw=none,fill=green!70!black}/closed polygon/{(xzmp),(xzm0),(O),(xz0p)},%
  {draw=none,fill=green!70!black}/closed polygon/{(xzmm),(xzm0),(O),(xz0m)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(xypp),(xzpp)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(xypm),(xzpp)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(xypp),(yzpp)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(xymp),(yzpp)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(xypm),(yzmp)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(xymm),(yzmp)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(xymp),(xzpm)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(yzmp),(xzpm)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(yzpp),(xzpm)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(yzmp),(xzpp)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(yzpp),(xzpp)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(yzmm),(xzmm)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(yzpm),(xzmm)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(yzmm),(xzmp)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(yzpm),(xzmp)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(xymm),(xzmm)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(xzpp),(xzpm)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(xypp),(xzmp)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(xypm),(xzmp)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(xypp),(yzpm)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(xymp),(yzpm)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(xypm),(yzmm)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(xymm),(yzmm)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(xymm),(xzmm)},%
  {draw,thick}/vertex poly/{(xymp),(xzmm)}}
  % normal of screen (last row of the rotation matrix)
  \path[overlay] ({sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*sin(\tdplotmainphi)},
       {-1*sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*cos(\tdplotmainphi)},
       {cos(\tdplotmaintheta)}) coordinate (n); 
  % build up the list of projections       
  \foreach \Style/\Poly/\CoordLst [count=\nC] in \PlaneData
  {%
  \GetProj{\CoordLst}{\currproj}
  \ifnum\nC=1
    \xdef\LstProj{\currproj}
  \else
    \xdef\LstProj{\LstProj,\currproj}
  \fi}
  % draw the planes in appropriate layers
  \foreach \Style/\Poly/\CoordLst [count=\nC] in \PlaneData
  {%
  \GetProj{\CoordLst}{\currproj}
  \setcounter{tdorder}{1}
  \foreach \Proj in \LstProj
  {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{ifthenelse(\Proj<\currproj,1,0)}
  \ifnum\itest=1
  \stepcounter{tdorder}
  \fi}
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{layer\number\value{tdorder}}
  \edef\temp{\noexpand\path[\Style,\Poly={\CoordLst}];}
  \temp
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I cann't download 3dtools, now.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Yes, I am really sorry. You can thank those who decided to harass me. It got to the point that I had to erase my GitHub account.

Comment: If I lost this tool, I can not compile a huge file.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 As I said, I am sorry, but this is not in my hands. Some user decided to mock me based on my GitHub correspondence. You can add a feature request on https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues, maybe Henri finds a way to resolve the situation. As long as certain aggressive comments are around, and as long as there is no guarantee that this won't repeat, I will not do anything with these repositories. Users have to learn that attacking others for using `B\'ezier` in a source code is inappropriate.