# Overlay diagrams in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to join the vertices labeled as (1), b, abc, and ac but could not succeed. I'd highly appreciate if you point me out what I'm doing wrong and what is the solution. Thanks

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 4, fill opacity = 1.0, thick,
                        line cap = round, line join = round]
    %% Define coordinate labels.
    % t(op) and b(ottom) layers
    \path \foreach \layer/\direction in {b/{0, 0, 0}, t/{0, 1, 0}} {
        (\direction)
        \foreach \point/\label in {{0, 0, 0}/ll, {1, 0, 0}/lr, {1, 0, -1}/ur, {0, 0, -1}/ul} {
            +(\point) coordinate (\layer\label)
        }
        ($(\layer ll)!0.5!(\layer ur)$) coordinate (\layer md)
    };



    % Put text next to the labels as requested.
    % Funilly enough we need to set fill opacity to 1.
    \draw \foreach \text/\label/\anchor in {%
        $\left(1\right)$/bll/east,
        $b$/bul/east,
        $c$/tll/east,
        $bc$/tul/east,
        $a$/blr/west,
        $ab$/bur/west,
        $ac$/tlr/west,
        $abc$/tur/west} {
        (\label) node[anchor=\anchor, fill opacity = 1] {\text}
    };
    % Draw  cube.
    \fill (0, 0, -1) circle (0.5pt);
    \foreach \direction in {(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0)} {
        \draw[dashed, black] (bul) -- + \direction;
    }


    \fill[red!60,   opacity=0.5]  (tll) -- (tul)  -- (bur) -- (blr);
    \fill[blue!60, opacity=0.5]  (bll)   -- (bul)   -- (tur) -- (tlr);




    \draw (bll) -- (blr) -- (tlr) -- (tll) -- cycle;
    \draw (blr) -- (bur) -- (tur) -- (tlr) -- cycle;
    \draw (tll) -- (tlr) -- (tur) -- (tul) -- cycle;

    \foreach \point in {bll, blr, bur, tll, tlr, tul, tur} {
        \fill[fill opacity=1] (\point) circle (0.75pt);
    }


\node[below] at (1.0, -0.2, 0.0) {$AC$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With your current coordinate system, it's as simple as a straight line from (1) to abc.

Comment: The four points are exactly on a line (try to replace `\fill` by `\filldraw`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply change the `z`-direction so that the points are no longer apparently collinear.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 4, thick,
    % change the z-direction
    z={(-0.3,-0.6)}]

    %% Define coordinate labels.
    % t(op) and b(ottom) layers
    \path \foreach \layer/\direction in {b/{0, 0, 0}, t/{0, 1, 0}} {
        (\direction)
        \foreach \point/\label in {{0, 0, 0}/ll, {1, 0, 0}/lr, {1, 0, -1}/ur, {0, 0, -1}/ul} {
            +(\point) coordinate (\layer\label)
        }
        ($(\layer ll)!0.5!(\layer ur)$) coordinate (\layer md)
    };

    % Put text next to the labels as requested.
    \draw \foreach \text/\label/\anchor in {%
        $\left(1\right)$/bll/east,
        $b$/bul/east,
        $c$/tll/east,
        $bc$/tul/east,
        $a$/blr/west,
        $ab$/bur/west,
        $ac$/tlr/west,
        $abc$/tur/west} {
        (\label) node[anchor=\anchor] {\text}
    };
    % Draw  cube.
    \fill (0, 0, -1) circle (0.5pt);
    \foreach \direction in {(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0)} {
        \draw[dashed, black] (bul) -- + \direction;
    }

    % add some midpoints for correct drawing of transparent planes
    \coordinate (m1) at ($(bll)!0.5!(tlr)$);
    \coordinate (m2) at ($(bul)!0.5!(tur)$);

    \fill[blue!60, opacity=0.5]  (bll)   -- (bul)   -- (m2) -- (m1) -- cycle;
    \fill[red!60,   opacity=0.5]  (tll) -- (tul)  -- (bur) -- (blr) -- cycle;
    \fill[blue!60, opacity=0.5]  (m1) -- (m2) -- (tur) -- (tlr) -- cycle;
    \draw[very thin, black!60] (m1) -- (m2);

    \draw (bll) -- (blr) -- (tlr) -- (tll) -- cycle;
    \draw (blr) -- (bur) -- (tur) -- (tlr) -- cycle;
    \draw (tll) -- (tlr) -- (tur) -- (tul) -- cycle;

    \foreach \point in {bll, blr, bur, tll, tlr, tul, tur} {
        \fill[fill opacity=1] (\point) circle (0.75pt);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Caramdir for your effort and spending time to resolve my issue with this overlay diagram. Thanks again.